# Angular 2: TypeError: core_1.NgModule is not a function

Tags: javascript, meteor, angular, pagination, angular2-meteor

I'm running a tutorial found here:

[https://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/search-sort-pagination-and-reactive-vars](http://Meteor%20&%20Angular2)

and I'm at the point where I'm implementing paging but its throwing an error. The console throws an error in parties-list.component.ts on line 7. The code at line 7 is:

```
import { PaginationService, PaginationControlsCmp } from 'ng2-pagination';
```

The FULL error thrown is:

```
 ng2-pagination.js:26Uncaught TypeError: core_1.NgModule is not a function
```

**I'm thinking maybe the ng2-pagination is not compatible with my version of angular I'm running inside of meteor but not sure how to find out.**

My package.js file:

```
{
  "name": "angular2-meteor-base",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor run",
    "test": "meteor test --driver-package practicalmeteor:mocha",
    "test:ci": "meteor test --once --driver-package dispatch:mocha-phantomjs"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "3.5.0",
    "chai-spies": "0.7.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-alpha.8",
    "angular2-meteor": "0.6.2",
    "angular2-meteor-accounts-ui": "^0.6.1",
    "angular2-meteor-auto-bootstrap": "0.6.0",
    "angular2-meteor-polyfills": "0.1.1",
    "angular2-meteor-tests-polyfills": "0.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.1",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "0.2.3",
    "ng2-pagination": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ng2-pagination/-/ng2-pagination-0.4.1.tgz",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "0.6.12"
  }
}
```

Comment: You are thinking well - your version of `ng2-bootstrap` isn't compatible with your version of Angular 2, had that same problem. I suggest you update all your Angular 2 packages and `ng2-bootstrap` to latest versions.

Comment: @StefanSvrkota , is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: You can find latest Angular 2 releases in `package.json` file, you should update your own to be like official one: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#!#create-and-configure Latest version of `ng2-bootstrap` is `1.1.5`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-bootstrap

Comment: I added my package.js file. I'm running inside meteor, so its not clear to me on which packages I should update

Comment: You should change your dependencies from `package.js` to match those from `package.json` from the link I provided. For example, `"@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4"` should be `"@angular/common": "2.0.0"` etc.

Comment: But, considering you are still using RC4, you will need to remodel your app significantly because modules were added in RC5. You can read more about it here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html And about migration to modules: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/rc4-to-rc5.html

Comment: I tried updating all my @angular dependencies and everything just broke --- I think meteor may depend on a certain version of angular, but then again why would this pagination step be in the tutorial?..hmmm.

Answer (score 2):

The [`ng2-pagination`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pagination) package makes use of the new `NgModule` (introduced in angular2 RC5 as stressed out by @StefanSvrkota in the question comments) since version `0.4.0`, released in npm on 09-Sep-2016.

You will note that this package is updated independently from the Angular2-meteor tutorial you are working with.

What simply happened is that the package author introduced a peer dependency (on angular2 version) compatibility issue in its latest versions.

You should be good by using a previous version of the package, when `NgModule` was not used yet:

```bash
$ npm uninstall --save ng2-pagination
$ npm install --save ng2-pagination@~0.3.0 # allow only patch version update
```

This should give you the version `< 0.4.0`, i.e. `0.3.5` currently.

Comment: Did not work...but now a different error:  :  modules.js :          _angular_core.createPlatformFactory is not a function

Comment: The last error was due to a bad state of my modules from all the npm install and uninstalls.... I ended up just taking the ng2-pagination out now  all is back to normal I'm gonna try a different paginaton module or custom component that will be more compatible

Comment: Version `0.3.5` of `ng2-pagination` worked without issue for me. You can try to re-install all your `node_modules` (simply delete the entire `node_modules` folder and execute `npm install` again).

Comment: I tried deleting all under node_modules, then running npm install... still same issue:   _angular_core.NgModule is not a function. In my package.json :  "ng2-pagination": "^0.3.5",

Comment: actually, I don't think its the ng2-pagination anymore....I see now that its throwing the error in another file now (  toolbar.umd.js ) -----  in my package.json file this is the dependency: @angular2-material/toolbar": "^2.0.0-alpha.6"